# Spring Data with two databases throws IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I work on a spring application which connects to two databases. Everything seemed fine with my configuration, simple finder methods for both database entities work as expected.

Now I have to do some magic with the criteria api. This is my code for a search form to find specific Report Objects:

```
@Override
public List<Report> findByCriteriaQuery(String lvg, String tnr, String fpd, String state, String reason,
        String version, String supervisor, String bel) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Report> reportQuery = cb.createQuery(Report.class);
    Root<Report> reportRoot = reportQuery.from(Report.class);

    reportQuery.select(reportRoot).distinct(true);

    Predicate reportCriteria = cb.conjunction();

    if(lvg != "") {
        Predicate p = cb.equal(reportRoot.get("lvg"), lvg);
        reportCriteria = cb.and(reportCriteria, p);
    }
    if(tnr != "") {
        Predicate p = cb.equal(reportRoot.get("tnr"), tnr);
        reportCriteria = cb.and(reportCriteria, p);
    }
    if(fpd != "") {
        Predicate p = cb.equal(reportRoot.get("fpd"), fpd);
        reportCriteria = cb.and(reportCriteria, p);
    }
    if(state != "") {
        Predicate p = cb.equal(reportRoot.get("orderState"), state);
        reportCriteria = cb.and(reportCriteria, p);
    }
    if(reason != "") {
        Predicate p = cb.equal(reportRoot.get("orderStateReason"), reason);
        reportCriteria = cb.and(reportCriteria, p);
    }
    if(version != "") {
        Predicate p = cb.equal(reportRoot.get("id").get("mobislversion"), version);
        reportCriteria = cb.and(reportCriteria, p);
    }
    if(bel != "") {
        Predicate p = cb.equal(reportRoot.get("bel"), bel);
        reportCriteria = cb.and(reportCriteria, p);
    }

    reportQuery.where(reportCriteria);

    List<Report> criteriaResult = em.createQuery(reportQuery).getResultList();

    List<Report> result = filterReportForSupervisor(supervisor, criteriaResult);

    return result;

}
```

At this line:

```
Root<Report> reportRoot = reportQuery.from(Report.class);
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class de.fraport.bvd.mobisl.data.shared.entity.Report
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.QueryStructure.from(QueryStructure.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl.from(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at de.fraport.bvd.mobisl.data.shared.repository.ReportRepositoryImpl.findByCriteriaQuery(ReportRepositoryImpl.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
at de.fraport.bvd.mobisl.data.shared.repository.ReportRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$87a17ef4.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at de.fraport.bvd.mobisl.data.shared.repository.ReportRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f86def2.findByCriteriaQuery(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
```

This seems strange to me, because queries like e.g.:

```
@Query("select r from Report r where r.id.created >= :now")
public Page<Report> findByDate(@Param("now") String now, Pageable pageable);
```

work absolutely correct. I have two config classes for the two databases where the entity manager factory beans scan for the correct entity packages and the class Report is annotated with @Entity.

Database 1:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.jdvc.fetch_size", 50);

    emf.setPackagesToScan("de.xxxxxx.bvd.xxxxxx.data.entity");
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    emf.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return emf;
}
```

Database 2:

```
@Bean(name="sharedEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sharedEntityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.jdvc.fetch_size", 50);

    emf.setPackagesToScan("de.xxxxxxx.bvd.xxxxxx.data.shared.entity");
    emf.setDataSource(sharedDataSource());
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    emf.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return emf;
}
```

Entity-Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_REPORT")
@Data
public class Report {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ReportPK id;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem was fairly simple. In the repository class which has the method findByCriteriaQuery I had to specify which entity manager I want to use there. I didn't know that fact. So this simple line does the trick:

```
@PersistenceContext (unitName = "sharedEntityManagerFactory")
private EntityManager em;
```